# postgres functions : difference between CASE WHEN and IF ELSE

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can any one let me know what the differences are between WHEN CASE .. and IF/ELSE when writing in Postgres functions.

Comment: The same as in most other languages: `CASE expression WHEN value THEN ... ELSE WHEN value THEN ...` vs. `IF expression = value THEN ELSE IF expression = value THEN ...`.

Comment: but both can be used in a function. AN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is *which `CASE` do you mean*?

One `CASE` is an **expression**. It can appear inside expressions, like `A + CASE ... + B`. Along with `COALESCE`, `NULLIF`, `GREATEST` and `LEAST` it makes the group of [conditional expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-conditional.html).

The other `CASE`, along with `IF`, is a **control structure** (a conditional). It can appear in the SQL control flow to chose what blocks/statements are executed, based on a condition.